# Animate CSS - Sintaxe correta?

Tags: css, css3, keyframes

Já tentei de diversas formas ajustar a animação simples de um @keyframes css ao qual estou fazendo. Ja vi diversas sintaxes e mesmo assim continuo com erro,

```css
.borda {
    padding: .5em;
    border: 20px solid transparent;    
    border-image: 20 repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 1em, transparent 0, transparent 2em,         #660000 0, #660000 3em, transparent 0, transparent 4em);
    font: 100%/1.6 Baskerville, Palatino, serif;     
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #990000; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1) inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 0 0 2px #990000;
    animation: animated 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animated
{
    0%
    {
        background-position: 0;
    }
    100%
    {
        background-position: 40px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="subscribebox" class="subscribebox borda">
... conteudo ....
</div>
```

onde estou errando ?

Comment: O elemento não tem background

Comment: O que você quer dizer com erro? Oq aparece pra vc?

Comment: Inclua o html na sua pergunta.

Comment: @dvd o elemento eh uma borda do tipo "airmail", pois quero dar movimento para ele e não consigo movimentá-lo.

Comment: <div id="subscribebox" class="subscribebox borda">
... conteudo ....
</div>

Comment: eu percebi, mas ele não é um background

Comment: Seu código nunca vai dar certo pq vc está animando o background não a borda...

Comment: @hugocsl alguma sugestão ? consigo transformar um border-image em background ?

Comment: Sim estou bolando uma resposta

Comment: Sério que a resposta do hugo ficou melhor? Não é por nada não, só queria saber, até pra eu aprender tb.

Comment: @dvd, não, eu estou usando o seu modelo, tanto que ficou muito legal em meu modelo aqui ao qual estou aplicando.

Comment: @dvd, agora estou trabalhando em como uma div ao qual tenho (hover) pode ficar por cima dessa borda. Se vc tiver alguma sugestão, agradeço.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Movimentar o `border-image` quando ele não é uma imagem acho que não tem jeito. A solução que encontrei foi criar um pseudo com o `border-image` que você quer e animar ele.

O interessante é que ele é todo autoajustável. Você não precisa mexer em nada, a não ser que queira ajustar as larguras etc.

Criei também uma `div` interna para o conteúdo:

```css
.borda {
    position: relative;
    padding: 1em;
    font: 100%/1.6 Baskerville, Palatino, serif;     
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #990000; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1) inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1), 0 0 0 2px #990000;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes animated
{
    from
    {
       left: -50%; /* metade do width */
    }
    to
    {
       left: 0%;
    }
}

.borda::after{
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   width: 150%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   border: 20px solid transparent;    
   border-image: fill 20 repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, red 0, red 1em, transparent 0, transparent 2em, #660000 0, #660000 3em, transparent 0, transparent 4em);
   animation: animated 10s linear infinite;
   z-index: -1;
}

.texto{
   background: #fff;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="borda">
   <div class="texto">
      Texto
      <br>
      Mais texto
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 90 segundos! :D

Comment: É, tava grande demais, diminuí :)

Comment: @dvd, o problema que estou enfrentando agora é, onde vc colocou Texto, Mais Texto, ali eu tenho uma div (hover) que ultrapassa a borda. Esse é o único problema que estou enfrentando agora, o resto ficou show.

Comment: @dvd onde eu adiciono o print aqui ?

Comment: Edita a pergunta, insere a imagem em qualquer lugar da pergunta, vai no final do texto da pergunta que vai ter o link da imagem... copia esse link e depois cancela a edição

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3qAt.jpg

Comment: isso, ele é uma div interna,  pois quando passo o ponteiro do mouse em cima, aparece esse balao, mas ele esta cortando, por ser um div interna. 
Se vc olhar nos cantos superiores esquerdo e direito, vera uns botões adicionais que eu coloquei, e estes estão fora da div de texto que vc colocou em seu modelo (Texto, mais texto). Eu estou apanhando com as posicoes da div interna (balao vermelho).

Comment: Essa div com a borda é fechada, não tem como colocar nada dentro dela que saia pra fora. Vc terá que fazer isso fora dela.

Comment: pensei que desse pra fazer, pois o máximo que consegui foi fazer da forma que fiz com o exemplo abaixo em minha área restrita do meu site .... paciencia !!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4yN3.jpg

Comment: Mas dá pra fazer. È só vc colocar tudo dentro de uma div e fazer o hover nessa div. Aí vc posiciona o balao como quiser por cima.

Comment: hover na div mais externa ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79333/discussion-between-eitaehnoiz-and-dvd).

Answer (score 2):

Segue o modelo, deixei comentado onde vc controla a largura das linhas, só não da para colocar uma de cada cor pq o efeito não funciona com `repite-linar` mas como o `linear-gradiente` normal.

**OBS:** não precisa de **animated.css** para isso, basta fazer uma animação simples de `background-position` com `@kayframes` mesmo

```css
.borda {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, 
                    #660000 0, 
                    #660000 25%, 
                    transparent 25%, 
                    transparent 50%, 
                    #660000 50%, 
                    #660000 75%, 
                    transparent 75%, 
                    transparent 100%);
  /* aqui vc controla a largura das linhas */
  background-size: 60px 60px; 
  border: 2px solid #660000;
  animation: linhas 2s linear infinite;
}
.txt {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1em;
  left: 1em;
  top: 1em;
  bottom: 1em;
  background-color: #fff;
}
@keyframes linhas {
  0% {
    background-position: 0, 30px;
  }
  100% {
    /* esse valor tem que ser o mesmo da largura da linha, background-size */
    background-position: 60px, 60px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="borda">
  <div class="txt"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show ! funcionou muito os dois codigos! Muito obrigado @dvd há dias estava tentando bolar algo, mas jamais iria achar que funcionaria com pseudo-classe.
So estou apanhando agora para sobre uma div transparente por cima da borda animada, quando faço o hover no texto ( dentro da classe texto) pois a imagem do hover é cortada justamente pelo tamanho da div da borda.

Comment: @EitaEhNOiz cara poste uma pergunta nova jovem! Assim como o código nos comentes não fica legal e tb não da para te responder direito nem postar exemplos como fizemos nem nada.... Abra uma nova pergunta que não tem problema, sempre tem alguém disposto a ajudar!

Comment: ok !irei fazer ...